# The movement of the point in orbit is one hundred long timesteps

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages

This list will produce a circular orbital plot:

```
eulerStep[{t_, state_List}, h_, f_List] := {t + h, state + h Through[f[{t, state}]]} solveSystemEuler[{t0_, state0_}, h_, n_Integer, f_List] := NestList[eulerStep[#, h, f] &, {t0, state0}, n] midptStep[{t_, state_List}, h_, f_List] := {t + h, state + h Through[ f[{t + 1/2 h, state + 1/2 h Through[f[{t, state}]]}]]} solveSytemMidPt[{t0_, state0_}, h_, n_Integer, f_List] := NestList[midptStep[#, h, f] &, {t0, state0}, n] L = 1/2 (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2) + 1/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2]; D[D[L, x'[t]], t] - D[L, x[t]] == 0 D[D[L, y'[t]], t] - D[L, y[t]] == 0 xdot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := vx vxdot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := -x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2) ydot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := vy vydot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := -y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2) start = {1, 0, 0, 1}; fcns = {xdot, vxdot, ydot, vydot}; orbit = solveSystemEuler[{0, start}, 0.01, 800, fcns]; xypts = orbit\[Transpose][[2]]\[Transpose][[{1, 3}]]\[Transpose]; ListPlot[xypts]
```

Orbital initial velocity is replaced by 1.25:

```
earthorbit=xypts;
spacestart = {1, 0, 0, 1.25};
orbit = solveSystemMidpt[{0, spacestart}, 0.01, 2200, fcns]; spacehiporbit = orbit\[Transpose][[2]]\[Transpose][[{1, 3}]]\[Transpose]; ListPlot[spacehiporbit]
```

Then put earth orbit on the same graph plot.

```
ListLinePlot[{earthorbit, spacehiporbit}, PlotStyle -> {Hue[0], Hue[0.66]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

I want to show is a few points along a hundred-long space orbit. i want to show 22 graphics like this but i doesn't work just the frame. Is my code correct? what's the problem?

```
Table[MultipleListPlot[Take[earthorbit, {n, n + 100}], Take[spaceshiporbit, {n, n + 100}], PlotJoined -> True, SymbolShape -> None, PlotStyle -> {Hue[0], Hue[0.66]}, PlotRange -> {{-3.6, 1.2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];, {n, 1, 2200, 100}];
```

then I change the code as follows:

```
Table[ListLinePlot[Take[earthorbit, {n, n + 100}], Take[spaceshiporbit, {n, n + 100}], PlotStyle -> {Hue[0], Hue[0.66]}, PlotRange -> {{-3.6, 1.2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];, {n, 1, 2200, 100}];
```

[image]

I hope someone can help me. Thank You

---

I want to show the graphics with codes in figure 4 from your mr. But even i tried to use your  codes, it doesn't my expected.
The graphics I want as below mr. Alex Trounev

[image]

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{Column[Column[orbit,2],1],Column[Column[orbit,2],2]}],AxesLabel->{"x","Vx"}]

ListPlot[Transpose[{Column[Column[orbit,2],3],Column[Column[orbit,2],4]}],AxesLabel->{"y","Vy"}]
```

Mr @Alex Trounev Im sorry.  This codes is very old version and i need you some help to fix this codes . sorry to make you very busy about my problem. Big thanks mr Alex Trounev.

```
vyvsy=Interpolation[Transpose[{Column[Column[Take[orbit,1100],2],4],Column[Column[Take[orbit,1100],2],3]}]]

vxvsx=Interpolation[Transpose[{Column[Column[Take[orbit,{550,1650}],2],2],Column[Column[Take[orbit,{550,1650}],2],1]}]]

vxvst=Interpolation[Transpose[{Column[Column[Take[orbit,-1100],2],2],Column[Take[orbit,-1100],1]}]]
```

Comment: It is difficult for the reader to advise on this question without some data to work with.

Comment: Here it's considered helpful to make the questions self sufficient, showing your own efforts and share all code in a [well formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) instead of links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. It's not fair to ask us to dig into the thread in another site to understand your problem. Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry..I use the mathematica version 10.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code contains several typos, after correcting which the code works. It is difficult to understand what the author wants. I understood that it is necessary to choose a certain number of points from the data (in my example, every fortieth)

```
eulerStep[{t_, state_List}, h_, f_List] := {t + h, 
  state + h Through[f[{t, state}]]} 
solveSystemEuler[{t0_, state0_}, h_, n_Integer, f_List] := 
 NestList[eulerStep[#, h, f] &, {t0, state0}, n] 
midptStep[{t_, state_List}, h_, f_List] := {t + h, 
  state + h Through[
     f[{t + 1/2 h, state + 1/2 h Through[f[{t, state}]]}]]} 
solveSytemMidPt[{t0_, state0_}, h_, n_Integer, f_List] := 
 NestList[midptStep[#, h, f] &, {t0, state0}, n] 
L = 1/2 (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2) + 
  1/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2]; eq = {D[D[L, x'[t]], t] - D[L, x[t]] == 0, 
  D[D[L, y'[t]], t] - D[L, y[t]] == 0}; 
xdot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := vx 
vxdot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := -x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2) 
ydot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := vy 
vydot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := -y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2) 
start = {1, 0, 0, 1}; fcns = {xdot, vxdot, ydot, vydot}; orbit = 
 solveSystemEuler[{0, start}, 0.01, 800, fcns]; xypts = 
 orbit\[Transpose][[2]]\[Transpose][[{1, 
    3}]]\[Transpose]; 
earthorbit = xypts;
spacestart = {1, 0, 0, 1.25};
orbit = solveSytemMidPt[{0, spacestart}, 0.01, 2200, 
  fcns]; spaceshiporbit = 
 orbit\[Transpose][[2]]\[Transpose][[{1, 
    3}]]\[Transpose]; 
ListLinePlot[{earthorbit, spaceshiporbit}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Hue[0], Hue[0.66]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]

{ListPlot[{Table[earthorbit[[n]], {n, 1, Length[earthorbit], 40}], 
   Table[spaceshiporbit[[n]], {n, 1, Length[spaceshiporbit], 40}]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Hue[0], Hue[0.66]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3.6, 1.2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic], 
 ListLinePlot[{Table[earthorbit[[n]], {n, 1, Length[earthorbit], 40}],
    Table[spaceshiporbit[[n]], {n, 1, Length[spaceshiporbit], 40}]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Hue[0], Hue[0.66]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3.6, 1.2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]}
```

[image: fig1]

```
Table[ListLinePlot[{Take[earthorbit, {n, n + 100}], 
   Take[spaceshiporbit, {n, n + 100}]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Hue[0], Hue[0.66]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3.6, 1.2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic], {n, 
  1, Min[Length[earthorbit], Length[spaceshiporbit]] - 100, 100}]
```

[image: fig2]
Align the data by length and create 22 patterns as the author wants.

```
orbit = solveSystemEuler[{0, start}, 0.01, 2200, fcns]; xypts = 
 orbit\[Transpose][[2]]\[Transpose][[{1, 3}]]\[Transpose];
earthorbit = xypts; Table[
 ListLinePlot[{Take[earthorbit, {n, n + 100}], 
   Take[spaceshiporbit, {n, n + 100}]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Hue[0], Hue[0.66]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3.6, 1.2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic], {n, 
  1, Min[Length[earthorbit], Length[spaceshiporbit]] - 100, 100}]
```

[image: fig3]

Coordinates and speed depending on time and speed depending on coordinate

```
orbit = solveSystemEuler[{0, start}, 0.01, 800, fcns];

{ListPlot[
  Table[{orbit[[i, 1]], orbit[[i, 2]][[1]]}, {i, 1, Length[orbit]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"}], 
 ListPlot[Table[{orbit[[i, 1]], orbit[[i, 2]][[2]]}, {i, 1, 
    Length[orbit]}], AxesLabel -> {"t", "Vx"}],
 ListPlot[
  Table[{orbit[[i, 2]][[1]], orbit[[i, 2]][[2]]}, {i, 1, 
    Length[orbit]}], AxesLabel -> {"x", "Vx"}]}
```

[image: fig4]
Interpolation of sample data

```
vyvsy = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{Take[orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 3]], 1100], 
     Take[orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 4]], 1100]}]];

vxvsx = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{Take[orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 1]], {550, 1650}], 
     Take[orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 2]], {550, 1650}]}]];

vxvst = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{Take[orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 1]], -1100], 
     Take[orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 2]], -1100]}]];
```

Dependencies of parameters in various combinations

```
orbit = 
 solveSystemEuler[{0, start}, 0.01, 800, fcns];
{ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 1]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 1]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"}],

 ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 1]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 2]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "Vx"}],

 ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 1]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 3]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"}],

 ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 1]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 4]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "Vy"}]}
{ListPlot[
  Transpose[{orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 1]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 2]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "Vx"}],

 ListPlot[
  Transpose[{orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 3]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 4]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"y", "Vy"}], 
 ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 1]], 
    orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 3]]}], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
 ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 2]], 
    orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 4]]}], AxesLabel -> {"Vx", "Vy"}]}
```

[image: fig5]
Another portion of the drawings. I repeat all the code so that there are no errors.

```
eulerStep[{t_, state_List}, h_, f_List] := {t + h, 
  state + h Through[f[{t, state}]]} 
solveSystemEuler[{t0_, state0_}, h_, n_Integer, f_List] := 
 NestList[eulerStep[#, h, f] &, {t0, state0}, n] 
midptStep[{t_, state_List}, h_, f_List] := {t + h, 
  state + h Through[
     f[{t + 1/2 h, state + 1/2 h Through[f[{t, state}]]}]]} 
solveSytemMidPt[{t0_, state0_}, h_, n_Integer, f_List] := 
 NestList[midptStep[#, h, f] &, {t0, state0}, n] 
L = 1/2 (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2) + 
  1/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + y[t]^2]; eq = {D[D[L, x'[t]], t] - D[L, x[t]] == 0, 
  D[D[L, y'[t]], t] - D[L, y[t]] == 0}; 
xdot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := vx 
vxdot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := -x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2) 
ydot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := vy 
vydot[{t_, {x_, vx_, y_, vy_}}] := -y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2) 
fcns = {xdot, vxdot, ydot, vydot};


spacestart = {1, 0, 0, 1.25};
orbit = solveSytemMidPt[{0, spacestart}, 0.01, 2200, fcns];


{ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 1]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 1]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "x"}],

 ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 1]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 2]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "Vx"}],

 ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 1]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 3]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"}],

 ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 1]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 4]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "Vy"}]}


{ListPlot[
  Transpose[{orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 1]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 2]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "Vx"}],

 ListPlot[
  Transpose[{orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 3]], orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 4]]}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"y", "Vy"}], 
 ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 1]], 
    orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 3]]}], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
 ListPlot[Transpose[{orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 2]], 
    orbit[[All, 2]][[All, 4]]}], AxesLabel -> {"Vx", "Vy"}]}
```

[image: fig6]

Comment: Alex Trounev, thank you for the time to replied my questions. I have to say sorry because my problem didnt yet solve. I want to show the graphic like this but it doesnt work just the frame. are the codes is right? i need your help. Thanks you mr. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDw2S.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDw2S.jpg)

Comment: @TeodoradaSilva I added a line of code and fig2.

Comment: Big thanks mr. Alex Trounev really appreciate your answer because it helpfull my problem, But after i tried to running your codes, the output running just show 8 graphics, i need more graphics to completed my problem ( 22 graphics). I need your time to solve my problem again.

Comment: The length of the orbits of the Earth and the satellite should be maintained as 800 and 2200, or can they be equalized as 2200 and 2200?

Comment: Thank you for the fast response mr Alex Trounev In this case.. I used 800 and 2200, but how the output if we used 2200 and 2200 ?

Comment: @TeodoradaSilva  I added a line of code and fig3. :)

Comment: Thank you mr. Alex Trounev You answers really help me to solve this problem...;)

Comment: I want to show the graphics like this with codes in figure 4 from your mr. But even i tried to use your  codes, it doesn't my expected.  Please help me mr. Alex Trounev..:(

Comment: You must use all the code from  `eulerStep` to `orbit=` and add code for fig4

Comment: Thank you mr. Alex Trounev . can you help me again correct the old version of the code that I attached above mr. This is my last question..  :(

Comment: @TeodoradaSilva I fixed your code.

Comment: Thank for your replied mr.@Alex Trounev for the graphics {x, vx} and {y, vy} after I tried your codes not yet to produce the graphics that I want. I have attached the graphics that I want above. I want to see the graphics form for the semi-minor  and the semi-major axis so that I can get the values ​​from Position versus velocity and perform data interpolation functions.. Please help me again mr@Alex Trounev ...

Comment: @TeodoradaSilva I do not see the picture.

Comment: @Mr.Alex Trounev, Can I send the picture by email ? Please give me your address. Thank you

Comment: See https://www.likalo.com/contact/

Comment: @Mr.Alex thank you. I haved send the picture in your email.. I need your response.

Comment: @TeodoradaSilva  I added a code and fig6. :)

Comment: Thank you very much mr.@Alex Trounev this is very helpful, you are very kind, Can you help me once again?. I have sent the results to your email, I have tried your code to make interpolation data function  but the results are not what I expected.

Comment: hello Mr.@Alex Trounev, I don't know what to say. At the moment, I want to thank you for everything because you have been willing to spend valuable time to solved my problem. The problem is solved now, once again I can only say thank you very much mr alex. May God accompany all your work, your activities, and your family.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @AlexTrounev sir, can you please see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290972/r-k-fourth-order-scheme-for-system-of-odes-containing-32-differential-equations once. I will be very grateful