# R-K fourth order scheme for system of ODEs containing 32 differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-conditions

In the present code, I am trying to solve the system of differential equations using the R-K fourth-order scheme. I am trying to plot the function u and T, but it is showing some error in the boundary conditions. Can anyone please help to identify the error? Suppose you need any further information. Kindly drop a comment. Thank you in advance.

Values for the constants

```
ph1 = 0.01; ph2 = 0.01; ph3 = 0.01; \[Rho]Mw = 2100; \[Rho]Mi = 5060; \
\[Rho]Ag = 10500; \[Rho]w = 997.1;
\[Rho]k = 783; \[Sigma]Mw = 10^-7; \[Sigma]Mi = 
 2.09*10^4; \[Sigma]Ag = 6.30*10^7; \[Sigma]w = 5.5*10^-6; \[Sigma]k =
  5*10^-11;
btMw = 2.8*10^-5; btMi = 2.8424*10^-5; btAg = 5.4*10^-5; btw = 
 21*((10)^(-5));
btk = 21*((10)^(-5)); CPMw = 711; CPMi = 397.746; CPAg = 235; CPw = \
4179; CPk = 2090;
\[Kappa]Mw = 3000; \[Kappa]Mi = 34.5; \[Kappa]Ag = 429; \[Kappa]w = \
0.613; \[Kappa]k = 0.15; muw = 0.001004; muk = 0.00151;
```

Ratios for the constants

```
mu = muw/muk; \[Rho] = \[Rho]w/\[Rho]k; \[Sigma] = \
\[Sigma]w/\[Sigma]k; bt = btw/btk; CP = CPw/CPk; \[Kappa] = \
\[Kappa]w/\[Kappa]k;
```

Physical parameters

```
m = 3; l = 3; l1 = 2; ep = 0.1; \[Beta] = 0.001; t = 
 Pi/3; \[Beta]1 = 1; \[Alpha] = 0; k = 1.5; la = 1; x = 10;
```

Some parameters

```
Gr = (Gr1*\[Rho]*bt)/mu; M = M1*Sqrt[\[Sigma]/mu]; b = 
 b1*Sqrt[\[Sigma]/mu]; H = 
 H1*Sqrt[\[Rho]/mu]; Pr = 6.84; \[CapitalOmega] = \[CapitalOmega]1/(
 mu*CP);
```

Some more constants

```
M1 = 1; b1 = 5; Gr1 = 0.5; H1 = 1; Pr1 = 21; \[CapitalOmega]1 = 1;
```

Some more ratios

```
A1 = 1/((1 - ph1)^2.5*(1 - ph2)^2.5*(1 - ph3)^2.5);
A2 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw)/\[Rho]w))*(1 - ph2)) + (
       ph2*\[Rho]Mi)/\[Rho]w)) + (ph3*\[Rho]Ag)/\[Rho]w;
A3 = ((\[Sigma]Ag*(1 + (2*ph3))) + (2*\[Sigma]w*B3*
       C3*(1 - ph3)))/((\[Sigma]Ag*(1 - ph3)) + (\[Sigma]w*C3*
       B3*(2 + ph3)));
B3 = ((\[Sigma]Mi*(1 + (2*ph2))) + (2*\[Sigma]w*
       C3*(1 - ph2)))/((\[Sigma]Mi*(1 - ph2)) + (\[Sigma]w*
       C3*(2 + ph2)));
C3 = ((\[Sigma]Mw*(1 + (2*ph1))) + (2*\[Sigma]w*(1 - 
         ph1)))/((\[Sigma]Mw*(1 - ph1)) + (\[Sigma]w*(2 + ph1)));
A4 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw*btMw)/(\[Rho]w*btw)))*(1 - 
           ph2)) + (ph2*\[Rho]Mi*btMi)/(\[Rho]w*btw))) + (
   ph3*\[Rho]Ag*btAg)/(\[Rho]w*btw);
A5 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw*CPMw)/(\[Rho]w*CPw)))*(1 - 
           ph2)) + (ph2*\[Rho]Mi*CPMi)/(\[Rho]w*CPw))) + (
   ph3*\[Rho]Ag*CPAg)/(\[Rho]w*CPw);
A6 = (\[Kappa]Ag + ((m - 1)*C6*B6*\[Kappa]w) - ((m - 1)*
       ph3*(C6*B6*\[Kappa]w - \[Kappa]Ag)))/(\[Kappa]Ag + ((m - 1)*C6*
       B6*\[Kappa]w) + (ph3*(C6*B6*\[Kappa]w - \[Kappa]Ag)));
B6 = (\[Kappa]Mi + ((m - 1)*C6*\[Kappa]w) - ((m - 1)*
       ph2*((C6*\[Kappa]w) - \[Kappa]Mi)))/(\[Kappa]Mi + ((m - 1)*
       C6*\[Kappa]w) + (ph2*((C6*\[Kappa]w) - \[Kappa]Mi)));
C6 = (\[Kappa]Mw + ((m - 1)*\[Kappa]w) - ((m - 1)*
       ph1*(\[Kappa]w - \[Kappa]Mw)))/(\[Kappa]Mw + ((m - 
         1)*\[Kappa]w) + (ph1*(\[Kappa]w - \[Kappa]Mw)));

A11 = 1/((1 - ph1)^2.5*(1 - ph2)^2.5*(1 - ph3)^2.5);
A12 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw)/\[Rho]k))*(1 - ph2)) + (
       ph2*\[Rho]Mi)/\[Rho]k)) + (ph3*\[Rho]Ag)/\[Rho]k;
A13 = ((\[Sigma]Ag*(1 + (2*ph3))) + (2*\[Sigma]k*B13*
       C13*(1 - ph3)))/((\[Sigma]Ag*(1 - ph3)) + (\[Sigma]k*C13*
       B13*(2 + ph3)));
B13 = ((\[Sigma]Mi*(1 + (2*ph2))) + (2*\[Sigma]k*
       C13*(1 - ph2)))/((\[Sigma]Mi*(1 - ph2)) + (\[Sigma]k*
       C13*(2 + ph2)));
C13 = ((\[Sigma]Mw*(1 + (2*ph1))) + (2*\[Sigma]k*(1 - 
         ph1)))/((\[Sigma]Mw*(1 - ph1)) + (\[Sigma]k*(2 + ph1)));
A14 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw*btMw)/(\[Rho]k*btk)))*(1 - 
           ph2)) + (ph2*\[Rho]Mi*btMi)/(\[Rho]k*btk))) + (
   ph3*\[Rho]Ag*btAg)/(\[Rho]k*btk);
A15 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw*CPMw)/(\[Rho]k*CPk)))*(1 - 
           ph2)) + (ph2*\[Rho]Mi*CPMi)/(\[Rho]k*CPk))) + (
   ph3*\[Rho]Ag*CPAg)/(\[Rho]k*CPk);
A16 = (\[Kappa]Ag + ((m - 1)*C16*B16*\[Kappa]k) - ((m - 1)*
       ph3*(C16*B16*\[Kappa]k - \[Kappa]Ag)))/(\[Kappa]Ag + ((m - 1)*
       C16*B16*\[Kappa]k) + (ph3*(C16*B16*\[Kappa]k - \[Kappa]Ag)));
B16 = (\[Kappa]Mi + ((m - 1)*C16*\[Kappa]k) - ((m - 1)*
       ph2*((C16*\[Kappa]k) - \[Kappa]Mi)))/(\[Kappa]Mi + ((m - 1)*
       C16*\[Kappa]k) + (ph2*((C16*\[Kappa]k) - \[Kappa]Mi)));
C16 = (\[Kappa]Mw + ((m - 1)*\[Kappa]k) - ((m - 1)*
       ph1*(\[Kappa]k - \[Kappa]Mw)))/(\[Kappa]Mw + ((m - 
         1)*\[Kappa]k) + (ph1*(\[Kappa]k - \[Kappa]Mw)));
```

Equations

```
With[{soln = {1 -> 1}}, u101[y_] := Sin[la*x]*g1[y] /. soln;
  u102[y_] := (m1[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*n1[y]) /. soln;
  u111[y_] := Sin[la*x]*g2[y] /. soln;
  u112[y_] := (m2[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*n2[y]) /. soln;
  u201[y_] := Sin[la*x]*g3[y] /. soln;
  u202[y_] := (m3[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*n3[y]) /. soln;
  u211[y_] := Sin[la*x]*g4[y] /. soln;
  u212[y_] := (m4[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*n4[y]) /. soln;
  u10[y_] := (u100[y] + ep*u101[y] + ep^2*u102[y]) /. soln;
  u11[y_] := (u110[y] + ep*u111[y] + ep^2*u112[y]) /. soln;
  u20[y_] := (u200[y] + ep*u201[y] + ep^2*u202[y]) /. soln;
  u21[y_] := (u210[y] + ep*u211[y] + ep^2*u212[y]) /. soln;
  T101[y_] := Sin[la*x]*f1[y] /. soln;
  T102[y_] := (h1[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*k1[y]) /. soln;
  T111[y_] := Sin[la*x]*f2[y] /. soln;
  T112[y_] := (h2[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*k2[y]) /. soln;
  T201[y_] := Sin[la*x]*f3[y] /. soln;
  T202[y_] := (h3[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*k3[y]) /. soln;
  T211[y_] := Sin[la*x]*f4[y] /. soln;
  T212[y_] := (h4[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*k4[y]) /. soln;
  T10[y_] := (T100[y] + ep*T101[y] + ep^2*T102[y]) /. soln;
  T11[y_] := (T110[y] + ep*T111[y] + ep^2*T112[y]) /. soln;
  T20[y_] := (T200[y] + ep*T201[y] + ep^2*T202[y]) /. soln;
  T21[y_] := (T210[y] + ep*T211[y] + ep^2*T212[y]) /. soln];
U[x_, y_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(u20[y] + (\[Beta]*(E^(I*t))*u21[y])), \[Alpha] <= y <= 
     1}, {(u10[y] + (\[Beta]*(E^(I*t))*u11[y])), -1 <= y <= \[Alpha]}}]
eq = {A1*(1 + 
        1/\[Beta]1)*(u100''[
         y] + (u100'[y]/(y + k))) - ((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*M^2)*
      u100[y] + ((A3*B3*C3*M*b) + l) + (A4*Gr*T100[y]) == 0, 
   A1*(1 + 1/\[Beta]1)*(u110''[
         y] + (u110'[y]/(y + k))) - (((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*
          M^2) + (I*A2*H^2))*u110[y] + l1 + (A4*Gr*T110[y]) == 0, 
   A11*(u200''[y] + (u200'[y]/(y + k))) - ((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(
         y + k))^2*M1^2)*
      u200[y] + ((A13*B13*C13*M1*b1) + (mu*l)) + (A14*Gr1*T200[y]) == 
    0, A11*(u210''[
         y] + (u210'[y]/(y + k))) - (((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*
          M1^2) + (I*A12*H1^2))*
      u210[y] + (mu*l1) + (A14*Gr1*T210[y]) == 0, 
   A1*(1 + 1/\[Beta]1)*(g1''[
         y] + (g1'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*g1[y])) - ((A3*
          B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*M^2)*g1[y] + (A4*Gr*f1[y]) == 0, 
   A1*(1 + 1/\[Beta]1)*(g2''[
         y] + (g2'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
          g2[y])) - (((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*M^2) + (I*A2*H^2))*
      g2[y] + (A4*Gr*f2[y]) == 0,
   A11*(g3''[
         y] + (g3'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*g3[y])) - ((A13*
          B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*M1^2)*g3[y] + (A14*Gr1*f3[y]) == 0,
   A11*(g4''[
         y] + (g4'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
          g4[y])) - (((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*M1^2) + (I*A12*
          H1^2))*g4[y] + (A14*Gr1*f4[y]) == 0,
   A1*(1 + 
        1/\[Beta]1)*(m1''[y] + (m1'[y]/(y + k))) - ((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(
         y + k))^2*M^2)*m1[y] + (A4*Gr*h1[y]) == 0,
   A1*(1 + 
        1/\[Beta]1)*(n1''[
         y] + (n1'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*n1[y])) - ((A3*
          B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*M^2)*n1[y] + (A4*Gr*k1[y]) == 0,
   A1*(1 + 
        1/\[Beta]1)*(m2''[
         y] + (m2'[y]/(y + k))) - (((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*
          M^2) + (I*A2*H^2))*m2[y] + (A4*Gr*h2[y]) == 0,
   A1*(1 + 
        1/\[Beta]1)*(n2''[
         y] + (n2'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
          n2[y])) - (((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*M^2) + (I*A2*H^2))*
      n2[y] + (A4*Gr*k2[y]) == 0,
   A11*(m3''[y] + (m3'[y]/(y + k))) - ((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*
        M1^2)*m3[y] + (A14*Gr1*h3[y]) == 0, 
   A11*(n3''[y] + (n3'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
          n3[y])) - ((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*M1^2)*
      n3[y] + (A14*Gr1*k3[y]) == 0,
   A11*(m4''[
         y] + (m4'[y]/(y + k))) - (((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*
          M1^2) + (I*A12*H1^2))*m4[y] + (A14*Gr1*h4[y]) == 0, 
   A11*(n4''[y] + (n4'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
          n4[y])) - (((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*M1^2) + (I*A12*
          H1^2))*n4[y] + (A14*Gr1*k4[y]) == 0,
   (((A6*B6*C6)/
        Pr)*(T100''[y] + (T100'[y]/(y + k)))) + (\[CapitalOmega]*
       T100[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
        Pr)*(T110''[
          y] + (T110'[y]/(y + k)))) + ((\[CapitalOmega] - (I*A5*H^2))*
       T110[y]) == 0,
   (((A16*B16*C16)/
        Pr1)*(T200''[y] + (T200'[y]/(y + k)))) + (\[CapitalOmega]1*
       T200[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
        Pr1)*(T210''[
          y] + (T200'[y]/(y + k)))) + ((\[CapitalOmega]1 - (I*A15*
           H1^2))*T210[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
        Pr)*(f1''[y] + (f1'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           f1[y]))) + (\[CapitalOmega]*f1[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
        Pr)*(f2''[y] + (f2'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           f2[y]))) + ((\[CapitalOmega] - (I*A5*H^2))*f2[y]) == 0,
   (((A16*B16*C16)/
        Pr1)*(f3''[
          y] + (f3'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           f3[y]))) + (\[CapitalOmega]1*f3[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
        Pr1)*(f4''[
          y] + (f4'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           f4[y]))) + ((\[CapitalOmega]1 - (I*A15*H1^2))*f4[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
        Pr)*(h1''[y] + (h1'[y]/(y + k)))) + (\[CapitalOmega]*h1[y]) ==
     0,
   (((A6*B6*C6)/
        Pr)*(k1''[y] + (k1'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           k1[y]))) + (\[CapitalOmega]*k1[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
        Pr)*(h2''[y] + (h2'[y]/(y + k)))) + ((\[CapitalOmega] - (I*A5*
           H^2))*h2[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
        Pr)*(k2''[y] + (k2'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           k2[y]))) + ((\[CapitalOmega] - (I*A5*H^2))*k2[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
        Pr1)*(h3''[y] + (h3'[y]/(y + k)))) + (\[CapitalOmega]1*
       h3[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
        Pr1)*(k3''[
          y] + (k3'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           k3[y]))) + (\[CapitalOmega]1*k3[y]) == 0,
   (((A16*B16*C16)/
        Pr1)*(h4''[
          y] + (h4'[y]/(y + k)))) + ((\[CapitalOmega]1 - (I*A15*
           H1^2))*h4[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
        Pr1)*(k4''[
          y] + (k4'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           k4[y]))) + ((\[CapitalOmega]1 - (I*A15*H1^2))*k4[y]) == 
    0};
```

Boundary conditions

```
bc = {u100[-1] == 0, u110[-1] == 0, u200[1] == 0, u210[1] == 0, 
   g1[-1] == -u100'[-1], g2[-1] == -u110'[-1], g3[1] == -u200'[1], 
   g4[1] == -u210'[1], m1[-1] == -(1/2)*(g1'[-1] - (1/2*u100''[-1])), 
   n1[-1] == -(1/2)*(g1'[-1] - (u100''[-1]/2)), 
   m2[-1] == -(1/2)*(g2'[-1] - (1/2*u110''[-1])), 
   n2[-1] == -(1/2)*(g2'[-1] - (u110''[-1]/2)), 
   m3[1] == -(1/2)*(g3'[1] + (1/2*u200''[1])), 
   n3[1] == (1/2)*(g3'[1] + (u200''[1]/2)), 
   m4[1] == -(1/2)*(g4'[1] + (1/2*u210''[1])), 
   n4[1] == (1/2)*(g4'[1] + (u210''[1]/2)), 
   u100[\[Alpha]] == u200[\[Alpha]], 
   u110[\[Alpha]] == 
    u210[\[Alpha]], (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(u100'[\[Alpha]]) == (u200'[\[Alpha]]), (mu*(1 \
+ 1/\[Beta]1))*(u110'[\[Alpha]]) == (u210'[\[Alpha]]), 
   g1[\[Alpha]] == g3[\[Alpha]], 
   g2[\[Alpha]] == 
    g4[\[Alpha]], (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(g1'[\[Alpha]]) == (g3'[\[Alpha]]), (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(g2'[\[Alpha]]) == (g4'[\[Alpha]]),
   m1[\[Alpha]] == m3[\[Alpha]], m2[\[Alpha]] == m4[\[Alpha]], 
   n1[\[Alpha]] == n3[\[Alpha]], 
   n2[\[Alpha]] == 
    n4[\[Alpha]], (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(m1'[\[Alpha]]) == (m3'[\[Alpha]]), (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(m2'[\[Alpha]]) == (m4'[\[Alpha]]), (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(n1'[\[Alpha]]) == (n3'[\[Alpha]]), (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(n2'[\[Alpha]]) == (n4'[\[Alpha]]), 
   T100[-1] == 0, T110[-1] == 0, T200[1] == 1, T210[1] == 0, 
   f1[-1] == -T100'[-1], f2[-1] == -T110'[-1], f3[1] == -T200'[1], 
   f4[1] == -T210'[1], h1[-1] == (-1/2)*(f1'[-1] - (T100''[-1]/2)), 
   h2[-1] == (-1/2)*(f2'[-1] - (T110''[-1]/2)), 
   h3[1] == (-1/2)*(f3'[1] + (T200''[1]/2)), 
   h4[1] == (-1/2)*(f4'[1] + (T210''[1]/2)), 
   k1[-1] == (-(1/2))*(f1'[-1] - (T100''[-1]/2)), 
   k2[-1] == (-(1/2))*(f2'[-1] - (T110''[-1]/2)), 
   k3[1] == (1/2)*(f3'[1] + (T200''[1]/2)), 
   k4[1] == (1/2)*(f4'[1] + (T210''[1]/2)), 
   T100[\[Alpha]] == T200[\[Alpha]], f1[\[Alpha]] == f3[\[Alpha]], 
   h1[\[Alpha]] == h3[\[Alpha]], k1[\[Alpha]] == k3[\[Alpha]], 
   T110[\[Alpha]] == T210[\[Alpha]], f2[\[Alpha]] == f4[\[Alpha]], 
   h2[\[Alpha]] == h4[\[Alpha]], 
   k2[\[Alpha]] == 
    k4[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     T100'[\[Alpha]] == 
    T200'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     f1'[\[Alpha]] == 
    f3'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*h1'[\[Alpha]] ==
     h3'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     k1'[\[Alpha]] == 
    k3'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     T110'[\[Alpha]] == 
    T210'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     f2'[\[Alpha]] == 
    f4'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*h2'[\[Alpha]] ==
     h4'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     k2'[\[Alpha]] == k4'[\[Alpha]]};
```

Solution Methodology

```
var = {u100, u110, u200, u210, g1, g2, g3, g4, m1, m2, m3, m4, n1, n2,
    n3, n4, T100, T110, T200, T210, f1, f2, f3, f4, h1, h2, h3, h4, 
   k1, k2, k3, k4};
coord = {y, -1, 1};
op = Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}};
var0 = Table[var[[i]]@y, {i, Length[var]}]; var1 = D[var0, y]; var2 = 
 D[var1, y];
sol0 = Solve[eq, var2];
sol01 = sol0 /. y -> 1; sol02 = sol0 /. y -> -1;
bc1 = bc /. sol01[[1]] /. sol02[[1]];
sol = NDSolve[{eq, bc1}, var, coord, op];
Plot[Evaluate[Re[var0] /. sol[[1]]], coord, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> var, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
{p1 = Plot[U[y] /. sol[[1]] // Re, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All],
 p2 = Plot[
   Piecewise[{{Re[(T20[y] + (\[Beta]*(E^(I*t))*T21[y]))], \[Alpha] <= 
        y <= 1}, {Re[(T10[y] + (\[Beta]*(E^(I*t))*T11[y]))], -1 <= 
        y <= \[Alpha]}}] /. sol[[1]], {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

Comment: There is messege from NDSolve::bvluc: `The equations derived from the boundary conditions are numerically ill-conditioned. The boundary conditions may not be sufficient to uniquely define a solution. If a solution is computed, it may match the boundary conditions poorly`.  Here you again use the 2nd derivative in the boundary conditions. This is prohibited in the solution methods used by the `NDSolve`. See this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285960/solving-a-system-of-ode-using-shooting-technique-with-ndsolve-command

Comment: @AlexTrounev Okay, sir, I will edit my accordingly. Thank you so much for the clarity sir

Comment: Please, check this parameter `((A3*B3*C3*M*b) + l)` in `eq[[1]]`. Now it is about 865333. Also parameter `M^2` is about 165438. It is too high for numerical integration.

Comment: @AlexTrounev sir, if I am not wrong, in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285960/solving-a-system-of-ode-using-shooting-technique-with-ndsolve-command we try to plot velocity and temperature separately, but in the present case we cannot do that, the equation is coupled in velocity equation temperature is also coming like h1, h2, h3 .... and so onn. And if it taking such a big value we can plot for M=0 also, sir.

Comment: Then see my answer for `M^2=1.5`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev sir, Here in the solution you are using chasing instead of shooting technique. What is the difference sir? In what ways it will effect solution

Comment: Could you please put this question under my answer?

Comment: @AlexTrounev done sir

Answer (score 2):

Parameter `M^2` is about 165438. It is too high for numerical integration. If we reduce this parameter to `M^2=1.5` then we have

```
(*Values for the constants*)

ph1 = 0.01; ph2 = 0.01; ph3 = 0.01; \[Rho]Mw = 2100; \[Rho]Mi = 5060; \
\[Rho]Ag = 10500; \[Rho]w = 997.1;
\[Rho]k = 783; \[Sigma]Mw = 10^-7; \[Sigma]Mi = 
 2.09*10^4; \[Sigma]Ag = 6.30*10^7; \[Sigma]w = 
 5.5*10^-6; \[Sigma]k = \[Sigma]w(*5*10^-11*);
btMw = 2.8*10^-5; btMi = 2.8424*10^-5; btAg = 5.4*10^-5; btw = 
 21*((10)^(-5));
btk = 21*((10)^(-5)); CPMw = 711; CPMi = 397.746; CPAg = 235; CPw = \
4179; CPk = 2090;
\[Kappa]Mw = 3000; \[Kappa]Mi = 34.5; \[Kappa]Ag = 429; \[Kappa]w = \
0.613; \[Kappa]k = 0.15; muw = 0.001004; muk = 0.00151;
(*Ratios for the constants*)

mu = muw/
  muk; \[Rho] = \[Rho]w/\[Rho]k; \[Sigma] = \[Sigma]w/\[Sigma]k; bt = 
 btw/btk; CP = CPw/CPk; \[Kappa] = \[Kappa]w/\[Kappa]k;
(*Physical parameters*)

m = 3; l = 3; l1 = 2; ep = 0.1; \[Beta] = 0.001; t = 
 Pi/3; \[Beta]1 = 1; \[Alpha] = 0; k = 1.5; la = 1; x = 10;
(*Some parameters*)

Gr = (Gr1*\[Rho]*bt)/mu; M = M1*Sqrt[\[Sigma]/mu]; b = 
 b1*Sqrt[\[Sigma]/mu]; H = 
 H1*Sqrt[\[Rho]/
    mu]; Pr = 6.84; \[CapitalOmega] = \[CapitalOmega]1/(mu*CP);
(*Some more constants*)

M1 = 1; b1 = 5; Gr1 = 0.5; H1 = 1; Pr1 = 21; \[CapitalOmega]1 = 1;
(*Some more ratios*)

A1 = 1/((1 - ph1)^2.5*(1 - ph2)^2.5*(1 - ph3)^2.5);
A2 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw)/\[Rho]w))*(1 - 
           ph2)) + (ph2*\[Rho]Mi)/\[Rho]w)) + (ph3*\[Rho]Ag)/\[Rho]w;
A3 = ((\[Sigma]Ag*(1 + (2*ph3))) + (2*\[Sigma]w*B3*
       C3*(1 - ph3)))/((\[Sigma]Ag*(1 - ph3)) + (\[Sigma]w*C3*
       B3*(2 + ph3)));
B3 = ((\[Sigma]Mi*(1 + (2*ph2))) + (2*\[Sigma]w*
       C3*(1 - ph2)))/((\[Sigma]Mi*(1 - ph2)) + (\[Sigma]w*
       C3*(2 + ph2)));
C3 = ((\[Sigma]Mw*(1 + (2*ph1))) + (2*\[Sigma]w*(1 - 
         ph1)))/((\[Sigma]Mw*(1 - ph1)) + (\[Sigma]w*(2 + ph1)));
A4 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw*btMw)/(\[Rho]w*btw)))*(1 - 
           ph2)) + (ph2*\[Rho]Mi*btMi)/(\[Rho]w*
          btw))) + (ph3*\[Rho]Ag*btAg)/(\[Rho]w*btw);
A5 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw*CPMw)/(\[Rho]w*CPw)))*(1 - 
           ph2)) + (ph2*\[Rho]Mi*CPMi)/(\[Rho]w*
          CPw))) + (ph3*\[Rho]Ag*CPAg)/(\[Rho]w*CPw);
A6 = (\[Kappa]Ag + ((m - 1)*C6*B6*\[Kappa]w) - ((m - 1)*
       ph3*(C6*B6*\[Kappa]w - \[Kappa]Ag)))/(\[Kappa]Ag + ((m - 1)*C6*
       B6*\[Kappa]w) + (ph3*(C6*B6*\[Kappa]w - \[Kappa]Ag)));
B6 = (\[Kappa]Mi + ((m - 1)*C6*\[Kappa]w) - ((m - 1)*
       ph2*((C6*\[Kappa]w) - \[Kappa]Mi)))/(\[Kappa]Mi + ((m - 1)*
       C6*\[Kappa]w) + (ph2*((C6*\[Kappa]w) - \[Kappa]Mi)));
C6 = (\[Kappa]Mw + ((m - 1)*\[Kappa]w) - ((m - 1)*
       ph1*(\[Kappa]w - \[Kappa]Mw)))/(\[Kappa]Mw + ((m - 
         1)*\[Kappa]w) + (ph1*(\[Kappa]w - \[Kappa]Mw)));

A11 = 1/((1 - ph1)^2.5*(1 - ph2)^2.5*(1 - ph3)^2.5);
A12 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw)/\[Rho]k))*(1 - 
           ph2)) + (ph2*\[Rho]Mi)/\[Rho]k)) + (ph3*\[Rho]Ag)/\[Rho]k;
A13 = ((\[Sigma]Ag*(1 + (2*ph3))) + (2*\[Sigma]k*B13*
       C13*(1 - ph3)))/((\[Sigma]Ag*(1 - ph3)) + (\[Sigma]k*C13*
       B13*(2 + ph3)));
B13 = ((\[Sigma]Mi*(1 + (2*ph2))) + (2*\[Sigma]k*
       C13*(1 - ph2)))/((\[Sigma]Mi*(1 - ph2)) + (\[Sigma]k*
       C13*(2 + ph2)));
C13 = ((\[Sigma]Mw*(1 + (2*ph1))) + (2*\[Sigma]k*(1 - 
         ph1)))/((\[Sigma]Mw*(1 - ph1)) + (\[Sigma]k*(2 + ph1)));
A14 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw*btMw)/(\[Rho]k*btk)))*(1 - 
           ph2)) + (ph2*\[Rho]Mi*btMi)/(\[Rho]k*
          btk))) + (ph3*\[Rho]Ag*btAg)/(\[Rho]k*btk);
A15 = ((1 - 
       ph3)*((((1 - ph1) + ((ph1*\[Rho]Mw*CPMw)/(\[Rho]k*CPk)))*(1 - 
           ph2)) + (ph2*\[Rho]Mi*CPMi)/(\[Rho]k*
          CPk))) + (ph3*\[Rho]Ag*CPAg)/(\[Rho]k*CPk);
A16 = (\[Kappa]Ag + ((m - 1)*C16*B16*\[Kappa]k) - ((m - 1)*
       ph3*(C16*B16*\[Kappa]k - \[Kappa]Ag)))/(\[Kappa]Ag + ((m - 1)*
       C16*B16*\[Kappa]k) + (ph3*(C16*B16*\[Kappa]k - \[Kappa]Ag)));
B16 = (\[Kappa]Mi + ((m - 1)*C16*\[Kappa]k) - ((m - 1)*
       ph2*((C16*\[Kappa]k) - \[Kappa]Mi)))/(\[Kappa]Mi + ((m - 1)*
       C16*\[Kappa]k) + (ph2*((C16*\[Kappa]k) - \[Kappa]Mi)));
C16 = (\[Kappa]Mw + ((m - 1)*\[Kappa]k) - ((m - 1)*
       ph1*(\[Kappa]k - \[Kappa]Mw)))/(\[Kappa]Mw + ((m - 
         1)*\[Kappa]k) + (ph1*(\[Kappa]k - \[Kappa]Mw)));
(*Equations*)

With[{soln = {1 -> 1}}, u101[y_] := Sin[la*x]*g1[y] /. soln;
  u102[y_] := (m1[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*n1[y]) /. soln;
  u111[y_] := Sin[la*x]*g2[y] /. soln;
  u112[y_] := (m2[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*n2[y]) /. soln;
  u201[y_] := Sin[la*x]*g3[y] /. soln;
  u202[y_] := (m3[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*n3[y]) /. soln;
  u211[y_] := Sin[la*x]*g4[y] /. soln;
  u212[y_] := (m4[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*n4[y]) /. soln;
  u10[y_] := (u100[y] + ep*u101[y] + ep^2*u102[y]) /. soln;
  u11[y_] := (u110[y] + ep*u111[y] + ep^2*u112[y]) /. soln;
  u20[y_] := (u200[y] + ep*u201[y] + ep^2*u202[y]) /. soln;
  u21[y_] := (u210[y] + ep*u211[y] + ep^2*u212[y]) /. soln;
  T101[y_] := Sin[la*x]*f1[y] /. soln;
  T102[y_] := (h1[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*k1[y]) /. soln;
  T111[y_] := Sin[la*x]*f2[y] /. soln;
  T112[y_] := (h2[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*k2[y]) /. soln;
  T201[y_] := Sin[la*x]*f3[y] /. soln;
  T202[y_] := (h3[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*k3[y]) /. soln;
  T211[y_] := Sin[la*x]*f4[y] /. soln;
  T212[y_] := (h4[y] + Cos[2*la*x]*k4[y]) /. soln;
  T10[y_] := (T100[y] + ep*T101[y] + ep^2*T102[y]) /. soln;
  T11[y_] := (T110[y] + ep*T111[y] + ep^2*T112[y]) /. soln;
  T20[y_] := (T200[y] + ep*T201[y] + ep^2*T202[y]) /. soln;
  T21[y_] := (T210[y] + ep*T211[y] + ep^2*T212[y]) /. soln];
U[x_, y_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(u20[y] + (\[Beta]*(E^(I*t))*u21[y])), \[Alpha] <= y <= 
      1}, {(u10[y] + (\[Beta]*(E^(I*t))*u11[y])), -1 <= 
      y <= \[Alpha]}}];

eq = {A1*(1 + 
        1/\[Beta]1)*(u100''[
         y] + (u100'[y]/(y + k))) - ((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*M^2)*
      u100[y] + ((A3*B3*C3*M*b) + l) + (A4*Gr*T100[y]) == 0, 
   A1*(1 + 1/\[Beta]1)*(u110''[
         y] + (u110'[y]/(y + k))) - (((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*
          M^2) + (I*A2*H^2))*u110[y] + l1 + (A4*Gr*T110[y]) == 0, 
   A11*(u200''[
         y] + (u200'[y]/(y + k))) - ((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*
        M1^2)*u200[y] + ((A13*B13*C13*M1*b1) + (mu*l)) + (A14*Gr1*
       T200[y]) == 0, 
   A11*(u210''[
         y] + (u210'[y]/(y + k))) - (((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*
          M1^2) + (I*A12*H1^2))*
      u210[y] + (mu*l1) + (A14*Gr1*T210[y]) == 0, 
   A1*(1 + 1/\[Beta]1)*(g1''[
         y] + (g1'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*g1[y])) - ((A3*
          B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*M^2)*g1[y] + (A4*Gr*f1[y]) == 0, 
   A1*(1 + 1/\[Beta]1)*(g2''[
         y] + (g2'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
          g2[y])) - (((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*M^2) + (I*A2*H^2))*
      g2[y] + (A4*Gr*f2[y]) == 0, 
   A11*(g3''[y] + (g3'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
          g3[y])) - ((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*M1^2)*
      g3[y] + (A14*Gr1*f3[y]) == 0, 
   A11*(g4''[y] + (g4'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
          g4[y])) - (((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*M1^2) + (I*A12*
          H1^2))*g4[y] + (A14*Gr1*f4[y]) == 0, 
   A1*(1 + 1/\[Beta]1)*(m1''[
         y] + (m1'[y]/(y + k))) - ((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*M^2)*
      m1[y] + (A4*Gr*h1[y]) == 0, 
   A1*(1 + 1/\[Beta]1)*(n1''[
         y] + (n1'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*n1[y])) - ((A3*
          B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*M^2)*n1[y] + (A4*Gr*k1[y]) == 0, 
   A1*(1 + 1/\[Beta]1)*(m2''[
         y] + (m2'[y]/(y + k))) - (((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*
          M^2) + (I*A2*H^2))*m2[y] + (A4*Gr*h2[y]) == 0, 
   A1*(1 + 1/\[Beta]1)*(n2''[
         y] + (n2'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
          n2[y])) - (((A3*B3*C3)*(k/(y + k))^2*M^2) + (I*A2*H^2))*
      n2[y] + (A4*Gr*k2[y]) == 0, 
   A11*(m3''[y] + (m3'[y]/(y + k))) - ((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*
        M1^2)*m3[y] + (A14*Gr1*h3[y]) == 0, 
   A11*(n3''[y] + (n3'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
          n3[y])) - ((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*M1^2)*
      n3[y] + (A14*Gr1*k3[y]) == 0, 
   A11*(m4''[y] + (m4'[y]/(y + k))) - (((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*
          M1^2) + (I*A12*H1^2))*m4[y] + (A14*Gr1*h4[y]) == 0, 
   A11*(n4''[y] + (n4'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
          n4[y])) - (((A13*B13*C13)*(k/(y + k))^2*M1^2) + (I*A12*
          H1^2))*n4[y] + (A14*Gr1*k4[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
         Pr)*(T100''[y] + (T100'[y]/(y + k)))) + (\[CapitalOmega]*
       T100[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
         Pr)*(T110''[
          y] + (T110'[y]/(y + k)))) + ((\[CapitalOmega] - (I*A5*H^2))*
       T110[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
         Pr1)*(T200''[y] + (T200'[y]/(y + k)))) + (\[CapitalOmega]1*
       T200[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
         Pr1)*(T210''[
          y] + (T200'[y]/(y + k)))) + ((\[CapitalOmega]1 - (I*A15*
           H1^2))*T210[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
         Pr)*(f1''[y] + (f1'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           f1[y]))) + (\[CapitalOmega]*f1[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
         Pr)*(f2''[y] + (f2'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           f2[y]))) + ((\[CapitalOmega] - (I*A5*H^2))*f2[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
         Pr1)*(f3''[
          y] + (f3'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           f3[y]))) + (\[CapitalOmega]1*f3[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
         Pr1)*(f4''[
          y] + (f4'[y]/(y + k)) - (la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           f4[y]))) + ((\[CapitalOmega]1 - (I*A15*H1^2))*f4[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
         Pr)*(h1''[y] + (h1'[y]/(y + k)))) + (\[CapitalOmega]*h1[y]) ==
     0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
         Pr)*(k1''[y] + (k1'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           k1[y]))) + (\[CapitalOmega]*k1[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
         Pr)*(h2''[y] + (h2'[y]/(y + k)))) + ((\[CapitalOmega] - (I*
           A5*H^2))*h2[y]) == 
    0, (((A6*B6*C6)/
         Pr)*(k2''[y] + (k2'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           k2[y]))) + ((\[CapitalOmega] - (I*A5*H^2))*k2[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
         Pr1)*(h3''[y] + (h3'[y]/(y + k)))) + (\[CapitalOmega]1*
       h3[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
         Pr1)*(k3''[
          y] + (k3'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           k3[y]))) + (\[CapitalOmega]1*k3[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
         Pr1)*(h4''[
          y] + (h4'[y]/(y + k)))) + ((\[CapitalOmega]1 - (I*A15*
           H1^2))*h4[y]) == 
    0, (((A16*B16*C16)/
         Pr1)*(k4''[
          y] + (k4'[y]/(y + k)) - (4*la^2*(k/(y + k))^2*
           k4[y]))) + ((\[CapitalOmega]1 - (I*A15*H1^2))*k4[y]) == 
    0};
(*Boundary conditions*)

bc = {u100[-1] == 0, u110[-1] == 0, u200[1] == 0, u210[1] == 0, 
   g1[-1] == -u100'[-1], g2[-1] == -u110'[-1], g3[1] == -u200'[1], 
   g4[1] == -u210'[1], m1[-1] == -(1/2)*(g1'[-1] - (1/2*u100''[-1])), 
   n1[-1] == -(1/2)*(g1'[-1] - (u100''[-1]/2)), 
   m2[-1] == -(1/2)*(g2'[-1] - (1/2*u110''[-1])), 
   n2[-1] == -(1/2)*(g2'[-1] - (u110''[-1]/2)), 
   m3[1] == -(1/2)*(g3'[1] + (1/2*u200''[1])), 
   n3[1] == (1/2)*(g3'[1] + (u200''[1]/2)), 
   m4[1] == -(1/2)*(g4'[1] + (1/2*u210''[1])), 
   n4[1] == (1/2)*(g4'[1] + (u210''[1]/2)), 
   u100[\[Alpha]] == u200[\[Alpha]], 
   u110[\[Alpha]] == 
    u210[\[Alpha]], (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(u100'[\[Alpha]]) == (u200'[\[Alpha]]), (mu*(1 \
+ 1/\[Beta]1))*(u110'[\[Alpha]]) == (u210'[\[Alpha]]), 
   g1[\[Alpha]] == g3[\[Alpha]], 
   g2[\[Alpha]] == 
    g4[\[Alpha]], (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(g1'[\[Alpha]]) == (g3'[\[Alpha]]), (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(g2'[\[Alpha]]) == (g4'[\[Alpha]]), 
   m1[\[Alpha]] == m3[\[Alpha]], m2[\[Alpha]] == m4[\[Alpha]], 
   n1[\[Alpha]] == n3[\[Alpha]], 
   n2[\[Alpha]] == 
    n4[\[Alpha]], (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(m1'[\[Alpha]]) == (m3'[\[Alpha]]), (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(m2'[\[Alpha]]) == (m4'[\[Alpha]]), (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(n1'[\[Alpha]]) == (n3'[\[Alpha]]), (mu*(1 + 
         1/\[Beta]1))*(n2'[\[Alpha]]) == (n4'[\[Alpha]]), 
   T100[-1] == 0, T110[-1] == 0, T200[1] == 1, T210[1] == 0, 
   f1[-1] == -T100'[-1], f2[-1] == -T110'[-1], f3[1] == -T200'[1], 
   f4[1] == -T210'[1], h1[-1] == (-1/2)*(f1'[-1] - (T100''[-1]/2)), 
   h2[-1] == (-1/2)*(f2'[-1] - (T110''[-1]/2)), 
   h3[1] == (-1/2)*(f3'[1] + (T200''[1]/2)), 
   h4[1] == (-1/2)*(f4'[1] + (T210''[1]/2)), 
   k1[-1] == (-(1/2))*(f1'[-1] - (T100''[-1]/2)), 
   k2[-1] == (-(1/2))*(f2'[-1] - (T110''[-1]/2)), 
   k3[1] == (1/2)*(f3'[1] + (T200''[1]/2)), 
   k4[1] == (1/2)*(f4'[1] + (T210''[1]/2)), 
   T100[\[Alpha]] == T200[\[Alpha]], f1[\[Alpha]] == f3[\[Alpha]], 
   h1[\[Alpha]] == h3[\[Alpha]], k1[\[Alpha]] == k3[\[Alpha]], 
   T110[\[Alpha]] == T210[\[Alpha]], f2[\[Alpha]] == f4[\[Alpha]], 
   h2[\[Alpha]] == h4[\[Alpha]], 
   k2[\[Alpha]] == 
    k4[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     T100'[\[Alpha]] == 
    T200'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     f1'[\[Alpha]] == 
    f3'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*h1'[\[Alpha]] ==
     h3'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     k1'[\[Alpha]] == 
    k3'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     T110'[\[Alpha]] == 
    T210'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     f2'[\[Alpha]] == 
    f4'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*h2'[\[Alpha]] ==
     h4'[\[Alpha]], ((\[Kappa]*A6*B6*C6)/(A16*B16*C16))*
     k2'[\[Alpha]] == k4'[\[Alpha]]};

(*Solution Methodology*)

var = {u100, u110, u200, u210, g1, g2, g3, g4, m1, m2, m3, m4, n1, n2,
    n3, n4, T100, T110, T200, T210, f1, f2, f3, f4, h1, h2, h3, h4, 
   k1, k2, k3, k4};
coord = {y, -1, 1};
op = Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "LineSearch"}, 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
     Table[var0[[i]] == 0 /. y -> -1, {i, Length[var]}]};
var0 = Table[var[[i]][y], {i, Length[var]}]; var1 = D[var0, y]; var2 =
  D[var1, y];
sol0 = Solve[eq, var2];
sol01 = sol0 /. y -> 1; sol02 = sol0 /. y -> -1;

bc1 = bc /. sol01[[1]] /. sol02[[1]];
sol = NDSolve[{eq, bc1}, var, coord, 
   Method -> {"Chasing", "ChasingType" -> "LinearChasing", 
     "ExtraPrecision" -> 10}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 10];
```

Please pay attention that we use `Method -> {"Chasing", "ChasingType" -> "LinearChasing","ExtraPrecision" -> 10}` instead of shooting method.
Visualization

```
{Plot[Evaluate[Re[var0] /. sol[[1]]], {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> var, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> Automatic], 
 p1 = Plot[U[0, y] /. sol[[1]] // Re, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All], 
 p2 = Plot[
   Piecewise[{{Re[(T20[y] + (\[Beta]*(E^(I*t))*T21[y]))], \[Alpha] <= 
        y <= 1}, {Re[(T10[y] + (\[Beta]*(E^(I*t))*T11[y]))], -1 <= 
        y <= \[Alpha]}}] /. sol[[1]], {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure1]

Update 1. Using Chasing method we can compute up to M^2=376 without warning from `NDSolve` and plot pictures as follows
[image: Figure 2]

While with shooting method we have in this case

```
NDSolve::bvluc: The equations derived from the boundary conditions are numerically ill-conditioned. The boundary conditions may not be sufficient to uniquely define a solution. If a solution is computed, it may match the boundary conditions poorly.

NDSolve::berr: The scaled boundary value residual error of 562.4155311689224` indicates that the boundary values are not satisfied to specified tolerances. Returning the best solution found.
```

Plotting results look like this
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: sir, Here in the solution you are using chasing instead of shooting technique. What is the difference sir? In what ways it will effect solution

Comment: Please, see Update 1 to my answer.

Comment: okay sir, Thank you sir